# Emacs ediff-show-registry ignores ediff-setup-windows-plain

Tags: emacs, emacs-ediff

I have the following in my .emacs file...

(setq ediff-window-setup-function 'ediff-setup-windows-plain)

and indeed ediff usually does it's work with split buffers (2 files and the Control Panel).

But if I type "R" (ediff-show-registry) in the Control Panel or M-x eregistry it pops up a new frame.  If I am looking at a file that is not part of an ediff session then M-x eregistry uses the same frame.

Is there a way to prevent eregistry from creating a new frame?

GNU Emacs 23.3.50.1 (i386-apple-darwin9.8.0, NS apple-appkit-949.54) of 2011-08-04 on braeburn.aquamacs.org - Aquamacs Distribution 2.3a
Ediff 2.81.4 of December 7, 2009

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way. Consider filing an enhancement request, using `M-x report-emacs-bug`. (Yes, that is also for enhancement requests.)